# Preserve 3D tactics and Firefox Quantum, other browsers

Tags: html, css, 3d

I was using some 3D CSS transforms to animate links with thumbnails over the past year or two based off a website I found stuff at called The Art of the Web. I posted the code on a JS Fiddle. This 3D animation worked in Firefox 57 and previous versions, but as of Firefox 58+ and Quantum it no longer works. When viewing it it all appears flat, and inspecting the element it renders a 3D matrix but does not display it in 3D, despite the preserve 3D elements being called.

https://jsfiddle.net/f00dl3/1Ludb783/1/

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spinner {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
        transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
}

#stage {
    perspective: 1200px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
    -moz-perspective: 1200px;
    -ms-perspective: 1200px;
}

#spinner {
    -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;

    animation-name: spinner;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 6s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#spinner:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

#spinner img {
    position: absolute !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Fix:**

Move all of the layout and display affecting CSS up one element to the immediate children of `#spinner`. ie `#spinner a`.

**Areas of note:**

`#stage` had an improper width, it should be the `offsetWidth` of a single immediate child element of `#spinner`. This was causing eccentric rotation.

The large gap in the carousel was due to unequal distribution of children across the available space (e.g. 360deg / children). If you add/remove children in the future, simply recalculate the offset `transform: rotateY(((360 / children) * n)deg) ...`.

**Updated Code:**
(some browser-specific code removed for brevity/clarity)

```css
@keyframes spinner {
 from {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }
 to {
  transform: rotateY(-360deg);
 }
}

#stage {
 width:160px;
 height:160px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:25px 0;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 perspective: 1200px;
}

#spinner {
 animation-name: spinner;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-duration: 6s;

 transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#spinner:hover {
 animation-play-state: paused;
}

#spinner a {
 padding: 4px;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 transform-origin: center;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#spinner img {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage">
 <div id="spinner">
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="(Development)">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(32.72deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Address Book">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(65.44deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Entertainment">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(98.16deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Facebook">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(130.88deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Finance Book">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(163.60deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Fitness">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(196.32deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="LinkedIn">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(229.04deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Local Map Server">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(261.76deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Resume">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(294.48deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="System Monitor">
  </a>
  <a href="#" style="transform: rotateY(327.20deg) translateZ(280px);">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png" alt="Weather">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I still don't quite comprehend how you can apply transformation and styling to a "a href" element but whatever - it works!

Comment: @user3260912 It might help to think of an HTML `<a>` element as comprised of two parts, structural and functional.

Structurally, it is eligible for the same styles and layout modifications as a `<div>` or most other HTMLElements. It has dimension and position and affects document flow.

Functionally, it may also act as a link to another resource. Just as an `<img>` may display an image, or an `<iframe>` may load another resource. These "qualities" will still be true if it's sized to a 10px square or fills the screen.

Regardless, the main issue was CSS non-inheritance.